# ASP.NET MVC: Create a dynamic view using interface as model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have an interface like so:

```
public interface ISettings
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }
```

and various implementations, for example:

```
public class SettingsA : ISettings
{
    public string Name { get { return "Example A"; } }

    public string CustomAttributeA1 { get; set; }

    public string CustomAttributeA2 { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsB : ISettings
{
    public string Name { get { return "Example B"; } }

    public string CustomAttributeB1 { get; set; }

    public string CustomAttributeB2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have the problem of needing to create a dynamic UI (pass `ISettings` as the model and generate controls based on the properties of each implementation). So I have this:

**Edit.cshtml:**

```
@model ISettings

@Html.EditorForModel(Model)
```

This is producing the required fields nicely, but the problem with this is I cannot easily customize it (example: add css classes for Bootstrap or whatever other CSS I might want).. I suppose I could use CSS selectors based on HTML tag.. but doesn't seem like the ideal approach. Is there some nice workaround to this issue? What's the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: A rough idea for a solution will be to write a reflection based, css class generator.

Comment: take a look at HTML Custom Editors in MVC. you can write up your own html extensions and get your desired result. Eg: @Html.MattEditorForModel(Model). It is really easy and clean way. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ashish_2008/htmlhelper-methods-in-Asp-Net-mvc1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution long ago and forgot to post back here... I can't post everything I did, but the basic idea is to add a property to the `ISettings` interface like:

```
public interface ISettings
{
    string Name { get; }

    string EditorTemplatePath { get; }
}
```

You then need to override this in each class. For example:

```
public class SettingsA : ISettings
{
    public string Name { get { return "Example A"; } }

    public string EditorTemplatePath
    {
        get{ return "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SettingsA.cshtml"; } 
    }

    public string CustomAttributeA1 { get; set; }

    public string CustomAttributeA2 { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsB : ISettings
{
    public string Name { get { return "Example B"; } }

    public string EditorTemplatePath
    {
        get{ return "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SettingsB.cshtml"; } 
    }

    public string CustomAttributeB1 { get; set; }

    public string CustomAttributeB2 { get; set; }
}
```

And of course you need to implement your own logic in a controller somewhere to return the custom HTML. For me, I use AJAX and do something like this:

```
[Route("get-editor-ui/{type}")]
public ActionResult GetEditorUI(string type)
{
    var model = // logic to get the model from "type" argument

    if (model == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    string content = RenderRazorPartialViewToString(model.EditorTemplatePath, model);
    return Json(new { Content = content }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

FYI, `RenderRazorPartialViewToString` is in my base controller and is defined as follows:

```
public string RenderRazorPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with some HTML helpers, like:

```
public static class MyHtmlExtensions
{
   public static string GetCssForMyDiv(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
   {
      if (htmlHelper.ViewData.Model is SettingsA) return "class-a";
      else if (htmlHelper.ViewData.Model is SettingsB) return "class-b";
      else return "";
   }
}
```

Never done this before *but* should work quite fine.

You'll have something like:

```
<div class="class-base my-class my-div-style @Html.GetCssForMyDiv()">
   Check my CSS classes!
</div>
```

You may play a little with IDisposable and have something cool as:

```
@using(var div = Html.BeginDivWithCustomCssClassPerType())
{
   <span>Check my CSS classes!</span>
}
```

These extensions might actually *help* you with your `EditorFor`. You might keep your `EditorFor` call which will render an EditTemplate for `ISettings` and there you'll place extension methods to provide diferent behavior on diferent inheritance cases.

Another approach is to simply have diferent `EditTemplate` elements, one for each concrete type (inheritance), if they differ a lot from each other, and call your `EditorFor` with the specific template name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the thing is I don't know what the types will be in advance. They are coming from plugins, so there's no way to know beforehand what the properties will be. I think the only way around this might need to add some GetHtml() method to my interface.. so each implementation can provide a unique UI.

Comment: Your core module cannot guess plugin methods - that's why you provide well-defined plugin contracts. You're guess around `GetHtml()` is correct. Define a contract with something like that and call that method within some `try-catch` because who knows if the plugin dev has(n't) place a `throw NotImplementedException()` anywhere...

Comment: Just to complement: method contracts is not the *only* way to go. For instance, you can define an attribute and use reflection on the extension class I've suggested to get custom attributes of a particular type, like `[OutputCssClass('my-css-class')]` or others. It's up to you, although method call is much faster than reflection to find attributes.

Comment: The thing I have realized as well is it's not just CSS, but things like data that need to be different for each.. for example: specifying the select list items for a dropdown. I am currently researching whether or not I can use some EditorTemplates from the plugin class libraries or not. If not, I think the only thing I can do is use some method as I suggested above. Thanks for your suggestions though anyway.

Comment: One implementation we have grants the customer the ability to add new fields/items into existing pages of our app. For that, we have an `IPlugin` contract which defines possibilities (eg: `SupportsCustomFields`, `SupportsCustomCss`, etc). When loading tenant-specific plugins, we take all plugins and build-up a cache. Afther that, when rendering our page (route-related constants available for plugin devs), we check if the plugin supports adding a field and if so, we load that field through a specific contract (eg: `IPluginFieldProvider.GetFieldsFor(string route)`).

Comment: This way, you let the plugins themselves decide on how they should be rendered, which data they should retrieve and all the "hows". For instance: you get a `LalaCompany.Settings` plugin through `IPlugin` and it has a `SupportCustomFields = true`. When rendering a page, you check `plugin.FieldsFor(PageConstantes.THIS_SPECIFIC_PAGE)` and if any (they should return a `IAddOnField` or similar), get the field type, props, classes (and data, for dropdown or tables) and render ;)